# Select Multiple (but not all) Elements of the Same Class with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

If i have a list of elements with the same class, I know I can select them by using querySelectorAll() to create the DOM list, and then either loop through them with a for loop if I want to change aspects of all of them, or I can pick out an individual instance of the class using bracket notation - i.e. myClass[0] for the first item.

What is the best way to select multiple (but not all) instances of the class.  I tried using myClass[0, 2, 7], but it only returns the last item in the DOM list.  I guess I could list them all individually myClass[0], myClass[2] etc, but this seems a bit long winded? Is this the only way to do it?

I have set up a codepen here: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/qmzJpX

Here is the code for quick reference with the two current ways of selecting items. It just seems there must be a better way?

HTML

```
<div class="changeme">Change Me</div>
<div class="changeme">Change Me</div>
<div class="changeme">Change Me</div>
<div class="changeme">Change Me</div>
<div class="changeme">Change Me</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;}

.changeme {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-family: arial
}
```

JS

```
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.changeme');

boxes[0].style.background = 'blue';

for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    boxes[1].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    boxes[3].style.backgroundColor = 'green';

}
```

Comment: just iterate over [0, 2, 7] and use boxes[index]

Comment: yeah no other way

Comment: Are the indices you are looking for fixed?

Comment: what exactly is the criteria for the nodes you want to select? Going by the index is a fragile construct.

Comment: Hi @juvian I don't know what you mean? How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which ones it is you want to keep or not keep but you could select them all and then filter out like so:

```
let boxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.changeme'))

let filteredBoxes = boxes.filter((box, index) => {
     // Perform the filtering operation here..

     return (index % 2 == 0) // Will only keep boxes with even indexes ( 0, 2, 4...)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo-selector in CSS. This allows you to select a specific child, range of children or do odd and even selection.

```css
.changeme:nth-child(2),
.changeme:nth-child(5) {
  background: blue;
}

.zebra:nth-child(odd) {
  background: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<h2>nth-child(x)</h2>
<div class="changeme">Change Me</div>
<div class="changeme">Change Me</div>
<div class="changeme">Change Me</div>
<div class="changeme">Change Me</div>
<div class="changeme">Change Me</div>

<h2>nth-child(odd)</h2>
<div class="zebra">Zebra Stripes</div>
<div class="zebra">Zebra Stripes</div>
<div class="zebra">Zebra Stripes</div>
<div class="zebra">Zebra Stripes</div>
<div class="zebra">Zebra Stripes</div>
<div class="zebra">Zebra Stripes</div>
<div class="zebra">Zebra Stripes</div>
<div class="zebra">Zebra Stripes</div>
```